# unclear python data structure and parse python

Tags: python, biopython

I have a small dataset that i'm using to get the global alignment results with BioPython's pairwise2 module. I have gotten so far to get the alignment and score results, and **now i have questions about the structure of the results and how i can parse them**

below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from Bio import pairwise2
from Bio.SubsMat import MatrixInfo as matlist

matrix = matlist.blosum62
match = 5
mismatch = -4 
gap_open = -10
gap_extend = -0.5


df = {'ID': ['H576','H577','H578'],
  'CD': ['GCACGCATAAGTAGT', 'GCGAGGGGGGCTTC', 'GCGAGAGATCGGG']}


df = pd.DataFrame(df)


dictionary = df.set_index('ID')['CD'].to_dict()

seq = dictionary.get('H576')

for seq0 in df.CD:
        alns = pairwise2.align.globalms(seq, seq0,  match, mismatch,    gap_open, gap_extend)
        print(alns)
```

the results:

```
 [('GCACGCATAAGTAGT', 'GCACGCATAAGTAGT', 75, 0, 15)]

 [('GCACGCATAAGTAGT-----', 'GCG------AGGGGGGCTTC', -15.5, 0, 20), ('GCACGCATAAGTAGT-----', 'GC------GAGGGGGGCTTC', -15.5, 0, 20)], ....]

 [('GCA------CGCATAAGTAGT', 'GCGAGAGATCG--------GG', -9.0, 0, 21), ('GC------ACGCATAAGTAGT', 'GCGAGAGATCG--------GG', -9.0, 0, 21)]GGGGGC--------TTCAGAGAGTTATAGGCTGTTTGACTAC', 'GTGAGAGATGCGCCGCGTATTC---GA-----AGCTTCTTTGACTAC', 55.5, 0, 47)],....]
```

**my questions:**

**Clearly the results contain 3 main sets, but what data structure is the results above? sets? tuples? sets and tuples?**

**I would like to only look at the first set of items from each set:**

```
('GCACGCATAAGTAGT', 'GCACGCATAAGTAGT', 75, 0, 15)

('GCACGCATAAGTAGT-----', 'GCG------AGGGGGGCTTC', -15.5, 0, 20)

('GCA------CGCATAAGTAGT', 'GCGAGAGATCG--------GG', -9.0, 0, 21)
```

**then in a loop, assign the first sequence of each set to be seq0 and second sequence of each seq to be seq1 and then i'm going to do something with them:**

so for first set:

```
seq0 = 'GCACGCATAAGTAGT'
seq1 = 'GCACGCATAAGTAGT'
```

second set:

```
seq0 = 'GCACGCATAAGTAGT-----'
seq1 = 'GCG------AGGGGGGCTTC'
```

third set:

```
seq0 = 'GCA------CGCATAAGTAGT'
seq1 = 'GCGAGAGATCG--------GG'
```

Comment: Please note, that the block "the results" is not possible with the script given, no matter what input. I presume you edited it, and it might be easier to not edit or to really remove uninteresting parts instead of inserting ellipsis, as people willing to understand the problem and give matching answers all have to correct this, if they want to deliver a working prototype including test data like I did in my answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that they are lists of tuples.

[] means list

() means tuple (read-only list)

The simpliest way to achieve what you are asking for is to index the items out of the list like so:

```
# Renamed seq0 so it doesn't interfere with below variable
for sequence0 in df.CD:
    alns = pairwise2.align.globalms(seq, sequence0,  match, mismatch, gap_open, gap_extend)
    # This is how you would get the first group of items from each tuple
    first_group_of_items = alns[0]

    # Now to get the seq variables you asked for
    # Since this variable is seq0, the above seq0 was renamed
    seq0 = first_group_of_items[0]
    seq1 = first_group_of_items[1]
```

I suspect that there is a much better naming strategy that you could use, but I don't know enough about biology to help you in that department.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have a list of tuples.

To access to the first element of each list you can just do:

```
list[0]
```

Because the list contains tuples it will return the complete tuple.

Then once you get your tuple you can take the first two values as:

```
seq0 = tuple[0]
seq1 = tuple[1]
```

If you don't want to store an intermediary value you can directly do:

```
seq0 = list[0][0]
seq1 = list[0][1]
```

I hope it helped. Have a nice day.

To add to the example:

```
In [16]: A =  [('GCACGCATAAGTAGT', 'GCACGCATAAGTAGT', 75, 0, 15)]

In [17]: A[0]
Out[17]: ('GCACGCATAAGTAGT', 'GCACGCATAAGTAGT', 75, 0, 15)

In [18]: A[0][0]
Out[18]: 'GCACGCATAAGTAGT'

In [19]: A[0][1]
Out[19]: 'GCACGCATAAGTAGT'
```

Answer (score 1):

Look like a `list` *[]* of `tuples` *()*.

If you're sure you want to keep the first, keep the first:

```
sequences = []
for seq0 in df.CD:
    alns = pairwise2.align.globalms(seq, seq0,  match, mismatch,    gap_open, gap_extend)
    sequences.append(alns[0])
```

This way you'll get:

```
sequences == [('GCACGCATAAGTAGT', 'GCACGCATAAGTAGT', 75, 0, 15),
              ('GCACGCATAAGTAGT-----', 'GCG------AGGGGGGCTTC', -15.5, 0, 20),
              ('GCA------CGCATAAGTAGT', 'GCGAGAGATCG--------GG', -9.0, 0, 21)]
```

Which is what you need, then to do something with them, just iterate over the list:

```
for seq1, seq2, *rest in sequences:
    # Do the job with seq1 and seq2...
```

If you care about the three values (and know what they mean) you should name them properly, not like me:

```
for seq1, seq2, name, this, properly in sequences:
    # Do the job with seq1, seq2, name, this, and properly.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want them stored in variables named `seq0`and `seq1`(and we ignore the invalid sample display of the `alns` content / output from your program in the question:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

alns_seq = (
    [('GCACGCATAAGTAGT', 'GCACGCATAAGTAGT', 75, 0, 15)],
    [('GCACGCATAAGTAGT-----', 'GCG------AGGGGGGCTTC', -15.5, 0, 20),
     ('GCACGCATAAGTAGT-----', 'GC------GAGGGGGGCTTC', -15.5, 0, 20)],
    [('GCA------CGCATAAGTAGT', 'GCGAGAGATCG--------GG', -9.0, 0, 21),
     ('GC------ACGCATAAGTAGT', 'GCGAGAGATCG--------GG', -9.0, 0, 21)]
)

for i, alns in enumerate(alns_seq, start=1):
    seq0, seq1 = alns[0][:2]
    print("Set No. %d:" % (i,))
    print(" seq0 = '%s'" % (seq0,))
    print(" seq1 = '%s'" % (seq1,))
```

yields:

```
Set No. 1:
 seq0 = 'GCACGCATAAGTAGT'
 seq1 = 'GCACGCATAAGTAGT'
Set No. 2:
 seq0 = 'GCACGCATAAGTAGT-----'
 seq1 = 'GCG------AGGGGGGCTTC'
Set No. 3:
 seq0 = 'GCA------CGCATAAGTAGT'
 seq1 = 'GCGAGAGATCG--------GG'
```

This should answer your above question and fulfill the requirements noted.

Some improvements are possible, and you can request them at any time ;-)